# Upload SVG image in the Image block in Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, svg, wordpress-gutenberg

Is there a way to upload SVG images in the Image block on the Gutenberg editor of WordPress.

I've tried using a plugin called *SVG Support* but it is still allowing me to upload the image.

It gives the following error:

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an `<xml>` tag. See the note at the top of 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/

Answer (score 3):

Add SVG support in your theme or plugin via following code snippet

```
/**
 * Allow SVG MIME Type in Media Upload
 *
 * @param array $mimes Mime types keyed by the file extension regex corresponding to those types.
*/
function cc_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );
```

For avoiding any security risk you can use this plugin ([Safe SVG](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-svg/)).

Answer (score 0):

Open your svg file and put this code in top of codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```